# Calculating length of array within an object within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm having trouble creating a loop that is referencing an array within an object within an array.

```
   var data_dictionary = [{
    "category": "Food",
    "items": [
        {
            "object": "Apple",
            "price": 2.21

        },
        {
            "object": "Banana",
            "price": 1.12
        }
     ]
  }, {
   "category":  "Goods",
   "items":  [
        {
            "object":  "Lawnmower",
            "price":   25.55
        },
        {
            "object":  "Bicycle",
            "price":   12.21
        }
     ]
  }
]
```

I would like to run a loop that will return the # of "objects", but I'm running into problems

```
var result =[] 
var temp = []
  for (var i=0; i < data_dictionary.length; i++) {
        for (var c=0; c < data_dictionary[i].items.length; c++) {
          temp.push (data_dictionary[i].items[c].object)
        }
      }
      result.push (temp.length)
```

The issue has to do with calculating the length in "c < data_dictionary[i].items.length", and likely in the following line as well.

Ideally, I would like result to be 4, since there are 4 objects.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: please add the wanted result. is it a number or an array with the objects with object inside?

Comment: Now your `data_dictionary` is the array with only one element. Is this a typo or a mistake?

Comment: your input data_dictionary is not a properly formed array ... Please check that .. Couple of brackets are missing ...

Comment: Your data_dictionary is not well formated in the first place. You're defining category and items twice inside the same object.

Comment: Your json object is wrong one json object cannot contain duplicate keys.
in your case you are dulicating "category" and "items" multiple time.

Comment: Sorry everyone - I had to copy over a fragment of the array manually and make a few mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

your data and code should be

```
var data_dictionary = [{
    "category": "Food",
    "items": [
        {
            "object": "Apple",
            "price": 2.21

        },
        {
            "object": "Banana",
            "price": 1.12
        }
     ]
  }, {
   "category":  "Goods",
   "items":  [
        {
            "object":  "Lawnmower",
            "price":   25.55
        },
        {
            "object":  "Bicycle",
            "price":   12.21
        }
     ]
  }
]

var result;
var temp = [];
for (var i=0; i < data_dictionary.length; i++) {
    for (var c=0; c < data_dictionary[i].items.length; c++) {
      temp.push (data_dictionary[i].items[c].object)
    }
}
result = temp.length
```

Comment: Thanks Parag - just updated it.  I had to write out a smaller aspect of the array and did it incorrectly..

Answer (score 0):

With a proper data structure (there is one `}, {` missing, as well as some strings are not terminated), you could build an array or just count the occurence.

```js
var data_dictionary = [{ "category": "Food", "items": [{ "object": "Apple", "price": 2.21 }, { "object": "Banana", "price": 1.12, }] }, { "category": "Goods", "items": [{ "object": "Lawnmower", "price": 25.55 }, { "object": "Bicycle", "price": 12.21 }] }],
    result = [];

data_dictionary.forEach(function (a) {
    a.items.forEach(function (b) {
        result.push(b.object);
    });
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly, you wanted the output as an array with inner arrays lengths.

first you should properly format your data to be valid,
then you can iterate over it using the [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function for instance:

```
var data_dictionary = [ {
    "category": "Food",
    "items": [
        {
            "object": "Apple",
            "price": '​2.21'
        },
        {
            "object": "Banana",
            "price": '1.12'
        }
     ]
  },
  {
   "category":  "Goods",
   "items":  [
        {
            "object":  "Lawnmower",
            "price":   '25.55'
        },
        {
            "object":  "Bicycle",
            "price":   '12.21'
        }
     ]
  }];


var result = data_dictionary.map(function(n) {
  return n.items.length;
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code missing the } and {, create separate object like below.

```
var data_dictionary = [{"category":"Food",
 "items":[
 {"object":"Apple",
  "price":"​2.21"
 },
 {"object":"Banana",
 "price":"1.12"
 }
 ]},

{"category":"Goods",
 "items":[{
  "object":"Lawnmower",
 "price":"25.55"
 },     
{
"object":"Bicycle",
"price":"12.21"
}]
}]
var $data_dictionary = $(data_dictionary);
```

You can use jQuery to write simple code.

```
var result = []; 
$data_dictionary.each(function(index,elt){
$(elt.items).each(function(itemIndex, itemElt){
 result.push(itemElt);
});});
```

here you will get 4 objects

Answer (score 0):

```
var object=[];

for(i = 0 ; i < data_dictionary.length; i++)
{
  object.push({'items':data_dictionary[i].object, 'itemsLength':data_dictionary[i].items.length});
}
```